# Javascript Date object set to null returns 12/31/1969

Tags: javascript

I am setting a javascript dateobject to null.  However, when I do a console log on the date, it shows 12/31/1969.  What is the correct way to check if a date is null in javascript if it is being converted to this type of date value?

Comment: `if(yourDate === null)` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you understand by "I am setting a javascript date object to null" but you can try this example and check if it works.

```js
let date = new Date();
date = null;

console.log(date); // null
```