# How to check string is valid date or not irrespective of pattern/format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I have tried `Date.parse()`, `Date()` and many other solution but no proper solution yet without checking it's pattern using regex(or external package like moment.js) first.

Attaching screenshot of sample which should be invalid date

e.g. Test - 7

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1353711/2472398

Comment: There's no reliable way to use the native Date API for this. You'll need to use a 3rd-party library, such as date-fns https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/isValid

Comment: What formats do you consider to be valid? E.g. "christmas 2015" is a legitimate date, but probably not one that you consider valid

Comment: @byxor 
Formats pattern used over here - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

Comment: @byxor I have tested "christmas 2015" and it's not actually converted to valid acceptable date e.g. 25 Dec 2015

Comment: @AlexGru I have tried now, it's not working as our date is a string object not date one.

Comment: @WillJenkins let me try this..

Comment: @WillJenkins from my understanding it's formatting utility - I think it does not help to validate date in this case.