# React-datepicker with custom input with manual typing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-datepicker

I am trying to create react-datepicker component with custom styled input:

```
<DatePicker
        selected={startDate}
        customInput={<CustomInput inputRef={inputRef} />}
        onChangeRaw={(e) => handleChangeRaw(e)}
        onChange={(date: Date | null) => {
          setStartDate(date);
        }}
      />

const CustomInput = forwardRef((props: any, ref) => {
  return <Input {...props} ref={ref} />;
});
```

I wanted to introduce validation (just simple validation that whatever user inputs will be formatted to the date so user cannot just type whatever he wants).

I created a function that would be formatting the input using onChangeRaw attribute in react-datepicker:

```
  const handleChangeRaw = (date) => {
    date.currentTarget.value = format(startDate, "dd/MM/yyyy");
  };
```

However after using this I cannot type anymore. Anyone has idea how to use manual typing with custom input in react-datepicker with simple validation function?

Here is recreated issue in the sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-datepicker-custominput-sample-forked-elx310?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
selected={startDate}
```

Here react-datepicker expects a `Date` object.

However, when you trigger `handleChangeRaw`, you get an change event, with some value (date.currentTarget.value), but thats not in the Date notation that datepicker expects.

So my take on this would be;

- `onChangeRaw`, convert the input value to a new Date.
- If the date [isn't valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript), just ignore the change
- Otherwise, create a new `Date`, and use `setStartDate` to change to that new date

```
const handleChangeRaw = (date) => {
      const newRaw = new Date(date.currentTarget.value);
      if (newRaw instanceof Date && !isNaN(newRaw)) {
        setStartDate(newRaw);
      }
  };
```

---

##### [Try it online](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-datepicker-custominput-sample-forked-fizf4j?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: I added one more validation condition to your function and even tough validation should be failing it allows for the change: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-datepicker-custominput-sample-forked-z8qeoy?file=/src/App.tsx:601-833, do you know why?

Comment: How do you mean 'allows for the change'? If I enter `09/05/2022abc` it fails and resets the value on focus loss.

Comment: I added one more condition where I calculate age based on the date picked from the calendar. If age is less than 1 the validation should fail and it also should reset. But in fact it will allow to select and write future dates which result in age less than 0. See my sandbox.

Comment: Yea thats because that change was handled by `onChange`, so it didn;t trigger our function. See [this updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-datepicker-custominput-sample-forked-49c46d?file=/src/App.tsx) where I made a single function for both handles, with the age check

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, you can add the following type to fix the typing.

```
const handleChangeRaw = (date: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (!startDate){
      return
    }
    date.currentTarget.value = format(startDate, "dd/MM/yyyy");
};
```

`date` should have the type `React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>`. Since `startDate` can be `null`, we have to check before using it. In this case I just return from the function. But you could also assign a default value here or something else.