# Check if const is valid date

Tags: google-apps-script

Hey i have a scrip that takes data for sheest and populates a gdoc file
one of the lines is a date

```
const friendlyDate = new Date(row[2]).toLocaleDateString();
```

but if there is not entered a date in the cell it returns "Invbalid Date" to the Gdoc file how whould i go about adding a if satement to check if there is a valid date in the cell and if not make the output text "Not registered on date"

I did try different if combinations but i am not that skilled in appscript

Answer (score 1):

From `Invbalid Date`, I thought that `row[2]` might be `""`. If my understanding is correct, although, unfortunately, I cannot know your whole script, how about the following modification?

#### Pattern 1:

```
const friendlyDate = row[2] && new Date(row[2]).toLocaleDateString();
```

- In this pattern, when `row[2]` is `""`, `friendlyDate` is `""`.

#### Pattern 2:

This is from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1353684).

```
const date = new Date(row[2]);
const friendlyDate = isNaN(date.getTime()) ? row[2] : date.toLocaleDateString();
```

- In this pattern, when `!isNaN(date.getTime())` is `true`, `friendlyDate` is the value of `date.toLocaleDateString()`. And, when `!isNaN(date.getTime())` is `false`, `friendlyDate` is `""`.

#### Note:

- When the value of `row[2]` is an invalid value for `new Date()`, if you want to return another value, please modify the above script.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
function test() {
  try {
    getDate( new Date() );
    getDate( 1 );
    getDate( "hello" ); 
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in test: "+err);
  }
}

function getDate(value) {
  try {
    if( value.constructor.name === "Date" ) {
      console.log(value.toLocaleDateString());
    }
    else {
      console.log("not a date")
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in doStuff: "+err);
  }
}

4:54:05 AM  Notice  Execution started
4:54:09 AM  Info    11/1/2022
4:54:09 AM  Info    not a date
4:54:09 AM  Info    not a date
4:54:06 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```