# Return null if incorrect date

Tags: javascript, date-parsing

I have many variables - year, month, day. I am trying to convert it to correct date form. I would like to get null if variables form incorrect date

```js
var year = "2023";
var month = "11"
var day = "31"
var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day);

// Log to console
console.log(date)
```

This code returns 1 December of 2023. But I would like to get null value. How do I do it?

Edit
I edited my code. I have dates like 30/11, 29/02, 31/04 which are not valid dates

Comment: PLease add more details, thats a valid date, why would you want null?

Comment: You would like to get a `null` value? For what purpose? A `null` value will not represent your date, or anything else for that matter.

Comment: `new` always returns an instance of the class specified, it will never return `null`.

Comment: And `Date` objects automatically handle overflow of dates. If a day number is higher than the number of days in the specified month, it wraps into the next month. So November 31 is not considered an error, it's just another way of saying December 1.

Comment: This is deliberate, it allows you to perform date arithmetic without having to handle crossing between days/months/years yourself.

Comment: Compare the year month day of the result with input values. They need to match. Simple.

Comment: Theres should be some content for your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition to check if the date is valid/not

```js
var year = "2023";
var month = "5";
var day = "32";

var date = new Date(parseInt(year), parseInt(month) - 1, parseInt(day));

if (isNaN(date) || date.getMonth() + 1 !== parseInt(month) || date.getDate() !== parseInt(day)) {
  date = null;
}

console.log(date);
```