# Checking if a date is valid in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting an “invalid date” Date instance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript)

Is there is a function `IsDate()` in javascript?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Try this:

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date instanceof Date && !isNaN(date.valueOf()));
```

This should return `true`.

*UPDATED: Added `isNaN` check to handle the case commented by [Julian H. Lam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122353/julian-h-lam)*

Comment: `new Date('derp') instanceof Date  // true`

Comment: @JulianH.Lam I've added a isNaN validation to the valueOf property to handle this case. Thanks!!!

Comment: Returns true for new Date('06/31/2016') since Javascript converts that to 7/1/2016.  Returns false for 06/32/2016 however.  Just something to keep in mind.  Only drawback.

Comment: @JulianH.Lam - but then 'Do NOT Convert Me as a date 1' also returns true

Comment: i think is not trust, several tests with wrong date return true

Comment: Instead of  date instanceof Date you can also use Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]'   . The original source was found here 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643782/how-to-check-whether-an-object-is-a-date  .Thank you to both the accepted answer authors.

Comment: @FelipeMaricatoMoura If you found a counterexample date that fails for you, it's helpful to share what that date might be, exactly.

Comment: I've been searching for a way to consistently check whether a string is a valid date. Up to now everything has failed, including this. Using a random string ending with a number will evaluate as a correct date, so checking the validity or class will come back as TRUE. For reference: https://jsfiddle.net/juro/8ogz3sda/ .

Comment: I've actually expanded my example. Even using MomentJS's isValid() function is incorrect. It seems like JavaScript uses the Date.parse function - when it fails to evaluate the text, it just uses the numbers, so `new Date('Test 1')` evaluates to the same as `new Date('1')`. The only way to get it working correctly would be either to develop your own string parsing, or you could use https://date-fns.org/ - the `isValid()` function seems to work correctly.