# How to validate timestamp in js

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I need to check fox example 2117-09-15 00:00:41.0.
I saw similar topics but this `var valid = (new Date(timestamp)).getTime() > 0;`don't work.

Comment: could you give us more details and some code?

Comment: It works: https://jsfiddle.net/x5hmyyrz/

Comment: I have a variable of type Timestamp createdDate = (Timestamp)employeeObject[4];,while maintaining the form I need to check the value created Date or I get an error HTTP Status 500

Comment: Rahul Tripathi, 2117-09-15 00:00:41.0.wrong,timestamp max value <2038 year and >1970 year

Comment: @Александр:- Read the [specs](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1): `ECMAScript Number values can represent all integers from –9,007,199,254,740,992 to 9,007,199,254,740,992; this range suffices to measure times to millisecond precision for any instant that is within approximately 285,616 years, either forward or backward, from 01 January, 1970 UTC.`

Comment: Do you want to check if the current time is the same as the 2117-09-15 00:00:41.0.?

Comment: I want to check that the values was not greater than the maximum or minimum timestamp values

Comment: MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual : The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check that a date is valid in MySQl then you could check that it is between some dates (min and max of mySql timestamp):

```
function isValid(dateString) {
    var minDate = new Date('1970-01-01 00:00:01');
    var maxDate = new Date('2038-01-19 03:14:07');
    var date = new Date(dateString);
    return date > minDate && date < maxDate;
}
```

Here is a fiddle for you to test: https://jsfiddle.net/x5hmyyrz/3/

Comment: Also, maybe not all browsers support date direct comparison. In that case use date.getTime() > minDate.getTime() && date.getTime() < maxDate.getTime()

Answer (score -2):

As seen here: [Checking if a date is valid in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589732/checking-if-a-date-is-valid-in-javascript), maybe you can use :

```
var date= new Date(timestamp)
valid = (date instanceof Date && !isNaN(date.valueOf()));
```