# Angular Material DatePicker ng-model includes time

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

```
<md-input-container>
        <label>Enter date</label>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="newResearch.plannedStartDate"></md-datepicker>
</md-input-container>
```

the value of the planned start date is " 1985-03-05T16:00:00.000Z "
i need the value to be exactly 1985-03-05 only.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible because `ng-model` requires a Date. From the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdDatepicker):

[image]

"1985-03-05T16:00:00.000Z" is actually the way `console.log()` displays the Date object (possibly using JSON.stringify()).

If you check this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/kkRjqN?editors=1010#0), you will see that the following lines of code:

```
console.log(typeof $scope.newResearch.plannedStartDate);
// This is a check for a Date object from Christoph's answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/643827/782358
console.log(typeof $scope.newResearch.plannedStartDate.getMonth === 'function');
console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.newResearch.plannedStartDate));
```

produce the following output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your controller please apply this:

```
var newDate = $filter('date')(value, "yyyy-MM-dd");
$scope.newResearch.plannedStartDate = newDate;
```

By use of filter you can achieve what your needs.

Comment: i really like to have an automatic binding to the variable "newResearch.plannedStartDate" with the use of ng-model in date picker. using that in controller requires something to be triggered before converted.

Comment: You need to do this at that time when date going to be save in database, and when it is going to be show in md-datepicker, don't forget to keep data-type of this field as date in mysql.