# d3.js filter() not displaying expected results

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

The filter command is not working as I expected. How would I refactor the code to get the requested output?

In the `.filter((d,i) => condition)` syntax, **`d`** is an object with the **x** *(date/time string)* and **y** *(num cars produced that shift)* axis values for that datapoint and **`i`** is the index of that datapoint on the linechart. Why does `d.x != testdate#`? <sup>Note: *testdate1* and *testdate2*
 are datetime strings that precisely match two of the date/time strings in the datapoints</sup> 
While troubleshooting this, I also tried to view the `typeof` for d.x with no success.

Test1 - commented out - inverse of tests 2 and 3, and it works *(demonstrates that the condition in tests 2 and 3 is not being matched because the code to show the dots works)*
Test2 - Not seeing greendot class on Mon Jan 04 08:00 data point (shorthand syntax)
Test3 - Not seeing reddot class on Sat Jan 02 08:00 data point (traditional syntax, diff datapoint)
Test4 - Similar to above, using console.log
Test5 - testing typeof - console.log displays nothing, console.dir displays only text word "object"
Test6 - console.log shows that one of the datapoints is a perfect match for testdate1

<kbd>[**jsFiddle for experimenting**](http://jsfiddle.net/q55vLng4/)</kbd>

```js
clearconsole();
var chartWidth = 500;
var myCSV = [ 
{"shift":"1","date":"01/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"178","truck":"125","bike":"317","moto":"237"},
{"shift":"2","date":"01/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"125","truck":"189","bike":"125","moto":"273"},
{"shift":"3","date":"02/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"140","truck":"219","bike":"328","moto":"1252"},
{"shift":"4","date":"02/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"222","truck":"290","bike":"432","moto":"378"},
{"shift":"5","date":"03/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"200","truck":"250","bike":"420","moto":"319"},
{"shift":"6","date":"03/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"230","truck":"220","bike":"310","moto":"413"},
{"shift":"7","date":"04/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"155","truck":"177","bike":"377","moto":"180"},
{"shift":"8","date":"04/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"179","truck":"203","bike":"405","moto":"222"},
{"shift":"9","date":"05/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"208","truck":"185","bike":"360","moto":"195"},
{"shift":"10","date":"05/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"150","truck":"290","bike":"315","moto":"280"},
{"shift":"11","date":"06/01/2016/08/00/00","car":"200","truck":"220","bike":"350","moto":"205"},
{"shift":"12","date":"06/01/2016/17/00/00","car":"230","truck":"170","bike":"390","moto":"400"},
];
var testdate1 = 'Mon Jan 04 2016 08:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)';
var testdate2 = 'Sat Jan 02 2016 08:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)';
lc1 = dc.lineChart("#line1");

var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y/%H/%M/%S");
myCSV.forEach(function (d) {
 d.date = dateFormat.parse(d.date);
});

myCSV.forEach(function (d) {
 d['car'] = +d['car'];
});

//console.log(myCSV);

var facts = crossfilter(myCSV);
var dateDim = facts.dimension(function (d) {return d.date});

var carDim = facts.dimension(function (d) {return d['car']});
var dgCar = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {return d['car']});

var minDate = new Date ("2016-01-01T08:00:00.000Z");
var maxDate = new Date ("2016-01-06T17:00:00.000Z"); 

var maxY = d3.max(myCSV, function(d) {return d['car']});

lc1
.renderArea(false)
.width(chartWidth)
.height(250)
.dimension(dateDim)
.group(dgCar)
.defined(function(d) {if(d.y !==null) {return d.y;}})
.transitionDuration(1000)
.margins({top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 35, left: 60})
.yAxisLabel('Cars')
.renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
.brushOn(false)
.x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]));
lc1.yAxis().ticks(5);
lc1.xAxis().ticks(3);

lc1.on('renderlet', function(lc1) {
console.log('myCSV.length: '+myCSV.length);
   var allDots1 = lc1.selectAll('circle.dot');
   //allDots1.filter((d,i) => i != testdate1).classed('pinkdot',true);
   allDots1.filter((d,i) => i === testdate1).classed('greendot',true);
   allDots1.filter(function(d){ return d.x===testdate2 }).classed('reddot',true);
   allDots1.filter(function(d){ if (d.x===testdate2) console.log('Found it') });
   allDots1.filter(function(d){ var xyz = d.x; console.dir(typeof xyz) });
   allDots1.filter((d, k) => console.log("\r\n["+d.x+"]\r\n["+testdate1+"]") );

});//END lc1.on(renderlet)

dc.renderAll();
dc.redrawAll();

function clearconsole(){
console.API;
if (typeof console._commandLineAPI !== 'undefined') {
    console.API = console._commandLineAPI; //chrome
} else if (typeof console._inspectorCommandLineAPI !== 'undefined') {
    console.API = console._inspectorCommandLineAPI; //Safari
} else if (typeof console.clear !== 'undefined') {
    console.API = console;
}
console.API.clear();
}
```

```css
svg{height:280px;width:500px;}
.greendot{stroke:green !important; fill:green !important; fill-opacity:1 !important;} 
.reddot{stroke:red !important; fill:red !important; fill-opacity:1 !important;}
.pinkdot{stroke:pink; fill:pink; fill-opacity:1 !important;}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.1/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/dc.js"></script>
<link href="http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<svg id="line1"></svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you compare dates, use `getTime()` method, eg.:

```
allDots1.filter(function(d){ 
    console.log(d.data.value, d.x, +d.x, testdate2, d.x===testdate2, +d.x===testdate2); 
    return +d.x===testdate2; // + is a shortcut for .getTime() 
  }).classed('reddot',true);
```

Additionally, you should set the timezone's offset,

```
var myCSV = [   
  {"shift":"1","date":"01/01/2016/08/00/00/+0500","car":"178","truck":"125","bike":"317","moto":"237"},
  {"shift":"2","date":"01/01/2016/17/00/00/+0500","car":"125","truck":"189","bike":"125","moto":"273"},
  {"shift":"3","date":"02/01/2016/08/00/00/-0500","car":"140","truck":"219","bike":"328","moto":"1252"},
  //...
];

//...

var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y/%H/%M/%S/%Z");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davcs86/1u2Lt95p/1/)

[Reference #1: Comparison of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/493018/2423859)

[Reference #2: Javascript's '+' unary operator](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/unary-add/)

[Reference #3: D3 v3 timeFormat](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md#format)

Comment: Thanks - great answer. Question: what is the `typeof` of `d.x` before you used the unary operator to convert it to a date?

Comment: `d.x` is an `Date Object`, but `typeof` returns `object` [MDN ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), but there are alternatives to check if an object is a `Date object`, like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/643827/2423859)

Comment: I recommend using `lodash` [https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isDate](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isDate)

Comment: Note - I am discovering new easter eggs you put into your answer every day. If there was a way to further upvote your answer I would do so. *Thanks for including/demonstrating the first/last date range trick in your jsFiddle demo.*

Answer (score 3):

`testdate` and `testdate2` are still strings when you're doing the equality check. Try parsing them with vanilla `new Date()` or d3's date/time functions:

`.filter(function(d){ return d.x >= new Date(testdate2); })`.

Careful to check what time zone the JS Date format is coming back in - the values might not be equal, even when they're both coming back as valid JS dates, if one is in a different time zone.