# Typescript: isNaN not accepting Date Object

Tags: typescript

```
const isObjectClass = (value: any, className: any) => (Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === `[object ${className}]`);

export const isDate = (value: any) => isObjectClass(value, 'Date');


const time = (time: Date): string => {
    return ((isDate(time) && !isNaN(time)) ? time : new Date()).toISOString();
};
```

In the above function `time`, I am checking if the input is a valid Date object or not. If valid, it will return the string version of passed Date. If invalid, it will return the string version of the current date.

The problem with `isDate()` is, it will return true for input values `new Date()` and `new Date(undefined))`. To avoid this I used `!isNaN()` which return false in case of `!isNaN( new Date(undefined) )`.

Now the problem is typescript is not allowing me to pass `Date` object to `isNaN` function.

**error**

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't pass a `Date` to `isNaN`? Use `time.valueOf()` to get its numerical value.

Comment: Use `!isNaN(+time)`

Comment: @ExplosionPills what does `+` do?

Comment: It casts to a number

Answer (score 6):

You can convert this date object to time (`!isNaN(time.getTime())`) like as follows,

```
const time = (time: Date): string => {
return ((isDate(time) && !isNaN(time.getTime())) ? time : new Date()).toISOString();
};
```

In here getTime method returns numeric value of the respective date object. So you can easily use this numeric value with isNaN

Answer (score -1):

That's maybe because you want to pass a number in your function time(), number can't be cast as Date.

isObjectClass and isDate are a bit useless, time already check the type of the argument.