# Why date variable is not instanceof Date, even though constructor is Date

Tags: javascript

Scratching my head trying to figure out why `myDate` is not an `instanceof Date`.

Can anyone explain? Is there any other debugging things I can try?

```js
//Defined in some other module
myDate = new Date();

// console.log output:
console.log(myDate);                   // 2019-11-17T05:00:00.000Z
console.log(typeof myDate);            // object   ✅
console.log(myDate instanceof Object); // true     ✅
console.log(myDate.constructor);       // [Function: Date] ✅
console.log(myDate instanceof Date);   // false
```

Comment: What browser/runtime are you using? I get the following result when using latest Chrome.

`myDate = new Date(); myDate instanceof Date // true`

Comment: I've replaced your example with a snippet and that shows the expected behavior (`myDate instanceof Date === true`). You will have to add more info on your setup.

Comment: There's lots of discussion in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643782/how-to-check-whether-an-object-is-a-date

Comment: Yeah, when I try it outside my setup as well, I get expected results. Was hoping it was something silly. I'll have to see if I can figure out a a minimal test example of my setup.

Comment: What exactly does "*Defined in some other module*" mean? What kind of modules are you using, how are they loaded, any chance that it runs in a different realm? Btw, even if `myDate.constructor.name == "Date"` I bet that `myDate.constructor != Date`

Comment: It's hard to trace as the object is being passed around but `myDate.constructor != Date` logs `true` (tho eslint complains)

Comment: I've added console.log of `myDate` to ques. above if it helps any. In answer to the above questions, I'm running a Create React App in Node (v13.1.0) environment with TypeScript. No browser.

Comment: Those are the direct console logs and —  I agree — it makes no sense. However, isn't the idea to troubleshoot things that don't make sense so we can learn? Closing won't help that endeavour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was that this was occurring within a test suite, which was attempting to mock or override the global Date object

```js
    global.Date = class extends Date {
      constructor() {
        super();
        return constantDate;
      }
    };
```

Hence the weird behaviours.