# Identifying a function name or property in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using an npm module that throws an empty function i.e. `UnauthorizedException` upon error. I want to be able to identify the function thrown so i can handle it accordingly

```
function UnauthorizedException() {

}

const f = () => {
  throw (new UnauthorizedException());
};

try {
  f();
} catch (err) {
  // How to identity a function name/property/etc so I can handle the error accordingly
  console.log(err);
  console.log(typeof (err));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UnauthorizedException` function is used as constructor. You can check if an object was created from a constructor using the [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator:

```js
function UnauthorizedException() {}

const f = () => {
  throw (new UnauthorizedException());
};

try {
  f();
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err instanceof UnauthorizedException);
}
```

Comment: If this *is* the answer, though, surely this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643782/how-to-check-whether-an-object-is-a-date) and a bunch of others?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't aware it's a duplicate. Yes that is what I'm looking for i.e. instanceof. Thanks a lot