# `instanceof Date` not behaving as expected within a BigQuery UDF

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

Anyone have any insight into why the following results in `false` instead of `true`?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION test()
RETURNS BOOL
LANGUAGE js
AS
"""
const d = new Date();
return d instanceof Date;
""";
SELECT test();
```

> Returns `false` *(unexpected)*

---

WORKAROUND:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION test()
RETURNS BOOL
LANGUAGE js
AS
"""
const d = new Date();
return Object.prototype.toString.call(d) === '[object Date]';
""";
SELECT test();
```

> Returns `true` *(as expected)*

Answer (score 0):

The `instanceof Date` seams not to work.

For other objects, like `String` it works fine.

[There is a JavaScript workaround possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643782/how-to-check-whether-an-object-is-a-date):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION test()
RETURNS  BOOL
LANGUAGE js
AS
"""
var  d = new Date();
var s= new String('String created with constructor');
//return s instanceof String;
return typeof d.getMonth === 'function';
""";

SELECT test();
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I came up with a similar workaround...

return Object.prototype.toString.call(d) === '[object Date];

Mainly just wanted to share this quirk as it cost me hours to track a bug down to this behavior.