# how to use persian datepicker add function?

Tags: datepicker, farsi

in my laravel project, i use persian datepicker and have a problem with add function.

```
new persianDate().add(String, Number);
```

My problem is that in this function, the return date is calculated from today's date, while I want to define the initial date myself.
For example, I have a start date and a deadline, and I want to calculate the completion date.
I am waiting for guidance.

```
 <script>
$('#deadline').change(function() {
var dval =parseInt($('#deadline').val());
var startdate=document.getElementById("startdate").value;
                                                  
var inputF = document.getElementById("enddate"); 
edate=new persianDate().format();

edate=new persianDate().add('days', dval).format('YYYY/MM/DD');

inputF.value = edate; 
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://github.com/babakhani/PersianDate#date)?

Comment: yes, and not found any thing,https://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/beta/persian-date/#add

Comment: https://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/beta/persian-date/#date "_You can create a persianDate with a pre-existing native Javascript Date object._" should help

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean? There are code examples on that same page. You set your initial date and then `.add()` something to it

Comment: i am very Beginner in javascript ,Please write the code I need.

Comment: I put all my code above

Comment: You will either have to create a Date instance out of your `startdate` string first, or you will have to take that date string apart into its individual components, so that you can pass them to the `persianDate` constructor via an array.

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? You were already able to create a new persiandate() and you also added some days to it

Comment: I don't want deadline to be added to the current date, it want be added to startdate

Comment: Links have been posted that show how to set your own starting date, instead of the current date, did you read them?

Comment: in line 4 of top code i get startdate from input element by stratdate id

Comment: Indeed - and then never use it. You then use a `new persianDate()` (which uses the current date) to add days to instead of applying the logic from the documentation we posted. `var day = new Date(2011, 9, 16);
var dayWrapper = new persianDate(day);` Use `daywrapper` to add the days to. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Note: This will NOT work here due to the missing library however this should work.

- You appear to be using jQuery for the change event handler so I added that just to match yours.
- Since `this` is the deadline element inside the function we can just use the `this.value` for that.
- You then get the `startdate` element value however I wrapped it in the `new Date()`
- You can use `const` instead of `var` to be more modern in your code.

```js
$('#deadline').on('change', function(event) {
  const dval = parseInt(this.value);
  const startval = document.getElementById("startdate").value;
  if (startval !== '') {
    $('.messages').text(`Start Date is ${startval} with type ${typeof startval}`);
    const startDate = new Date(startval);
    const startDateMS = startDate.getTime()
    console.log(startDateMS, typeof startDateMS);
    const inputF = document.getElementById("enddate");
    const edate = new persianDate(startDateMS).add('days', dval).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
    inputF.value = edate;
  } else {
    $('.messages').text("Start Date is not a date");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Start Date:</label>
<input id="startdate" type="date" lang="fa" />
<label>Deadline days:</label>
<input id="deadline" type="number" lang="fa" />
<label>End Date:</label>
<input id="enddate" type="date" />
<div class="messages"></div>
```

Comment: this error apear: The specified value "NaN/NaN/NaN" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: It looks like your library might accept a number as a "new date" so here I put some very rudimentary validation in place on the date and passed it that number; I did NOT check this against that library or do any deeper reading on the format method of that. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date  Also for some basic validation if it is a date: https://stackoverflow.com/q/643782/125981